# Is there a common code to change the date format(timestamp) to Number format

Tags: java, spring-boot-2

I am using SpringBoot 2.2. date format is **"validFrom": "2013-12-31T18:30:00.000+0000"**
But I want in number format (like **1411471800000**).
In my entity I included the below code snippet which worked in Number format.

```
@JsonProperty("updDate")
**@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)**
private Date updDate;
```

To achieve that, I will have to do in all my entities.Is there a way where I can make one change and it will apply for all date formats.

Please advise

Comment: Please try `spring.jackson.date-format= # Date format string (e.g. yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss), or a fully-qualified date format class name (e.g. com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat)` in your aplication.properties file of spring book.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom Serializer for `Date` type which will used to serialize `Date` type.

```
public class DateSerializer extends StdSerializer<Date> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -7880057299936791237L;

  public JacksonLocalDateSerializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  public JacksonLocalDateSerializer(Class<Date> type) {
    super(type);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
      SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    jsonGenerator.writeNumber(value.getTime());
  }
}
```

and add it in object mapper so that `Date` type object always serialize using your custom serializer

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(Date.class, new DateSerializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```